# Handling a "cannot find symbol class" error

Tags: android, android-fragments, import

I am learning from Big Nerd Ranch, the code is same as in the book
Error is in CrimeActivity class where I am calling new CrimeFragment().
I have imported support library but it is still there. Is there any other way to handle fragments?

Thank-you in advance !!

CrimeActivity class -->

```
package com.example.shivam.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();  // error
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

}
```

CrimeFragment class-->

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.shivam.criminalintent.R;

public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {
     private Crime mCrime;
     private EditText mTitleField;

         @Override
         public  void  onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
         mCrime = new Crime();
     }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime,container,false);
        mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                mCrime.setTitle(charSequence.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still there "cannot find symbol class CrimeFragment ". CrimeFragment is extending Fragment class.

Answer (score 3):

You are finding fragment by id, that id should be your fragment layout id, not container id.

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

replace to this:

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
f = new Fragment();
                    ((FragmentActivity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(ContainerId, f).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank-you everyone.

Also By changing this -- import com.example.shivam.criminalintent.R;
with -- package com.example.shivam.criminalintent;
solved the problem.
Auto importing is now working fine.

```
Fragment fragment =(com.example.shivam.criminalintent.CrimeFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {

            fragment = new com.example.shivam.criminalintent.CrimeFragment();

            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
```